# Tableau Reporting

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently using Tableau for my reporting module. However, I have several issues I need answered. I tried the following; please comment if I am on the right track.

1. I want to embed Tableau generated report to my website, so I used [Javascript API](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/help.htm#JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm). My data may come from Tableau Online (Cloud Server), or Tableau Server, for now I used **Tableau Online**.
2. Now, I have to create my *report* so I used Tableau Desktop to create how my report would look like. Tableau Desktop can connect to my local DB for get data.
3. Then, I published my *workbook* to my server . However, in Tableau Online, I need to data connection which fails since I don't have a live server.
4. I downloaded Tableau Server but I can't proceed since in configuration it want an Active Directory credentials.

I haven't done any output, I think I am stuck. I would welcome some input.

Comment: You think you are stuck?!?

Answer (score 2):

Tableau supports both Active Directory and Local Authentication Mode. We have tableau server running in local authentication mode but however its not highly advisable to run the server in local authentication.

If you have installed tableau server in active directory mode, reinstall the server. During your reinstall select local authentication as the default authentication. Once you have installed it, you need to add on Administrator Account.

Another workaround is go to All Programs > Tableau Server > Configure Tableau Server. In General Tab, you will be having the User Authentication. Try changing it if its enabled. If its disabled you need to reinstall tableau.

below are the steps to reinstall tableau server

Back up and remove Tableau Server

When Tableau Server has been uninstalled, open Windows Explorer and navigate to C:\Program Files\Tableau.

Delete the Tableau Server folder.

Navigate to the C:\ProgramData\Tableau.

Delete the Tableau Server folder.

Reinstall Tableau Server and restore the backup

Install Tableau Server. This step will allow you to set a new authentication method.

After installing Tableau Server, a browser window will display and you will be prompted to create a new administrator account. Ignore this, and close the browser window.

After restoring your backup file, a browser window will display and you will be prompted to create a new administrator account again. Ignore this, and close the browser window. If you are prompted to type in the Run As user password, type the password and continue with the next step. You will not see a password confirmation.

In the Command Prompt window, from the Tableau Server bin directory, type the following command to reset Tableau Server back to a state that requires an administrator account to be set up:

tabadmin reset

Open a browser window, and type http://localhost in the address bar to set up the administrator account for Tableau Server.

Answer (score 0):

I may have assumed that when you say Tableau Online, you dont mean the Tableau Public..
I assume your tableau online is your local or let's say company hosted tableau server...
for the answers to your questions in sequence
 1 - 3 it can be done.

tableau supports a lot of datasources even the classic text based data it can read..

did you tried installing your database drivers?

> If the server is configured to use local authentication, when you add
>   a user identity, you specify a username, a password and a site role.
>   In that case, the Tableau Server repository is used exclusively to
>   authenticate the user.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/security_auth.htm